# Formatting brackets

Tags: php, regex

Is there any better and more efficient way than following to format spaces around brackets? Is it possible to merge following in on RegEx?

```
$string = '(dd       ) ads          [d]';
$string = preg_replace([
        '#\s*(“)\s*([^”]+?)\s*?(”)\s*#u',
        '#\s*(«)\s*([^»]+?)\s*?(»)\s*#u',
        '#\s*(\()\s*([^)]+?)\s*?(\))\s*#u',
        '#\s*(\{)\s*([^}]+?)\s*?(\})\s*#u',
        '#\s*(\[)\s*([^\]]+?)\s*?(\])\s*#u',
    ],
    ' \1\2\3 ', $string);
echo trim($string); //(dd) ads [d]
```

It will convert these: `a  (b)  c`, `a(b)c`, `a(   b )c` and `a   (   b)c`  to `a (b) c`.

Comment: Can you give examples of what you are doing? It's hard to compile regexps in your head.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: I don't think this will work when you have nested brackets, it will only process the innermost ones.

Comment: Why do all your regexps have `[^)]+?`? Shouldn't these be the appropriate close bracket for that step?

Comment: FYI `preg_replace()` supports multiple inputs/replaces by using arrays.

Comment: @Barmar You are right. Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single expression:

```
$string = preg_replace('#\s*(?:(\[)\s*([^]]+?)\s*?(\])|' .
                              '(\{)\s*([^}]+?)\s*?(\})|' .
                              '(\()\s*([^)]+?)\s*?(\))|' .
                              '(«)\s*([^»]+?)\s*?(»)|' .
                              '(“)\s*([^”]+?)\s*?(”))\s*#u', 
                       ' \1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9\10\11\12 ', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `[...]` set.

Should the following not suffice (no pairing)?

```
$string = preg_replace('#\s*([\[\{\(«“])\s*#u', ' \1', $string);
$string = preg_replace('#\s*([\]\}\)»”])\s*#u', '\1 ', $string);
```